# Dynamically adding methods to the object doesn't work correctly (setattr)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to create a `class` to adapt `django` objects to the export. I want other programmers to always inherit from this `class` and if needed, they can override any attribute by overriding:

```
get__<attr_name>
```

method.

So what I do is that I iterate over `django` model fieldnames and for every fieldname, I set `get__<attr_name>` method. The problem is that all these methods returns the same `True` which is an output of the last fieldname.

```
class BaseProductExportAdapter():  
    def __init__(self, product: Product):
        self.product = product
        self.eshop = self.product.source.user_eshop

    def _set_methods(self):
        product_attr_names = Product.get_fieldnames(exclude=[])
        # set all getters so we can use get__<any_field> anytime. It can be overriden anytime.
        for attr_name in product_attr_names:
            setattr(self, 'get__' + attr_name, lambda: getattr(self.product, attr_name))
```

When I create a `BaseProductExportAdapter` instance and set `product` as an argument and call `b._set_methods()`, I see this:

```
>>> ...
>>> b._set_methods()
>>> b.get__quantity()
>>> True
>>> b.get__<any_valid_fieldname>()
>>> True
```

Do you know why it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: maybe `lambda x=attr_name: getattr(self.product, x)`. It usually works when `lambda` is used in `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `lambda` expression forms a closure that accesses the *current* value of variables in the scope in which they were defined. So in your `lambda` expression, when you ask for `attr_name` you're going to get the *current* value of `attr_name` in the scope of the `_set_methods` function.

This means that as you've defined your `_set_methods` method it's always going to be the last value of `attr_name` in your `for` loop.  Consider what happens if you set it explicitly after the `for` loop:

```
    def _set_methods(self):
        product_attr_names = Product.get_fieldnames(exclude=[])
        # set all getters so we can use get__<any_field> anytime. It can be overriden anytime.
        for attr_name in product_attr_names:
            setattr(self, 'get__' + attr_name, lambda: getattr(self.product, attr_name))
        attr_name = 'foo'
```

With the above code, `b.get__<anything>()` will always end up running `getattr(self.product, 'foo')`.

For more information, see e.g.:

- [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)
- https://louisabraham.github.io/articles/python-lambda-closures.html

You can work around the situation by replacing the `lambda` expression with a factory function:

```
    def _set_methods(self):
        def attrgetter(attr):
            def _():
                return getattr(self.product, attr)

            return _

        product_attr_names = Product.get_fieldnames(exclude=[])
        # set all getters so we can use get__<any_field> anytime. It can be
        # overriden anytime.
        for attr_name in product_attr_names:
            setattr(self, 'get__' + attr_name, attrgetter(attr_name))
```